# Java EE security - application clients

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I'm writing on a Java EE project which will have everything from 3-6 different clients. The project is open source, and I wonder what security mechanisms one could/should use. The problem is: Because it is open source, I would believe that it is possible for anyone with a user to write their own client (maybe not realistic, but truly possible) and make contact with the server/database. I've tried to go through all the scenarios of reading/writing different data to the database as different roles, and I conclude with that I have to have some security mechanism on a higher level than that (it is *not* enough to check if that account type is allowed to persist that entity with that ID and so on...). In some way I have to know that the client making contact is the correct client *I* wrote.  Could signing the Jar files solve this entire problem, or is there other ways to do it?

-Yngve

Answer (score 1):

I really think that if restricting the available activities on the server side (based on role) is not sufficient, than you've got a bigger problem.  Even if a user doesn't write their own client, whatever mechanism you are using for your remote calls is likely to be vulnerable to being intercepted and manipulated.  The bottom line is that you should limit the possible calls that can be made against the server, and should treat each call to the server as potentially malicious.

Can you think of an example scenario in which there's a server action that a particular authenticated user would be allowed to take that would be fine if they're using your client but dangerous if they're not using your client?  If so I'd argue that you're relying too strongly on your client.

However, rather than just criticize I'd like to try to also offer some actual answers to your question as well.  I don't think signing your jar file will be sufficient if you're imagining a malicious user; in general, public-key cryptography may not help you much since the hypothetical malicious user who is reverse-engineering your source will have access to your public key and so can spoof whatever authentication you build in.

Ultimately there has to be someone in the system you trust, and so you have to figure out who that is and base your security around them.  For example, let's imagine that there may be many users at a particular company who you don't necessarily trust, and one admin who oversees them, who you do trust.  In that scenario you could set up your client so that the admin has to enter a special code at startup, and have that code be kept in memory and passed along with any request.  This way, even if the user reverse-engineers your code they won't have the admin code.  Of course, the calls from your client to your server will still be vulnerable to being intercepted and manipulated (not to mention that this requirement would be a royal pain in the neck to your users).

Bottom line: if your user's machine is calling your server, than your user is calling your server.  Don't trust your user.  Limit what they can do, no matter what client they're using.

Answer (score 0):

Well the source may be available for anyone, but the configuration of the deployment and the database certainly isn't. When you deploy the application you can add users with roles. The easiest thing to do is to persist them in a database. Of course the contents of the table will only be accessible to the database administrator. The database administrator will configure the application so that it can access the required tables. When a user tries to log in, he/she must supply a username and password. The application will read the table to authenticate/authorize the user.

This type of security is the most common one. To be really secure you must pass the credentials over a secure path (HTTPS). For a greater degree of security you can use HTTPS client authentication. You do this by generating a public key for every client and signing this with the private key of the server. Then the client needs to send this signed key with every request.

EDIT: A user being able to write his/her own client doesn't make the application less secure. He/she will still not be able to access the application, if it is required to log in first. If the log in is successful, then a session (cookie) will be created and it would be passed with every request. Have a look at [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html). It does have a rather steep learning curve, but if you do it once, then you can add security in any application at a number of minutes.

Comment: I have roles with usernames/passwords (of course), but that does not solve the problem with users ability to write their own clients. But the latter part is interesting. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is it web you're talking about? This is not a web application, it is a distributed java EE app. If a user has a user/password pair, he could write his own client and use that user/pass. He would then be logged in. Woulnd't he? He surely would on our system as far as I know.

Comment: Are usernames and passwords hard-coded? In this terrible situation yes, he could log in. If these are checked against a database, then you can always change them. Distributed java EE apps also use sessions.

Comment: No, they are not hard-coded. Assume that you are a user with a user/pass stored in the database. Then you write your own app-client and log in with that user/pass. Of course you will also then get logged in, but be running your own code which will impose a security threat.